# Set up Trace Flag for Single Process in Process Builder

Tags: process-builder, debugging, process, traceflag

We have an unruly Lightning Process for our Opportunities. We are trying to troubleshoot the reason it is inconsistently failing. I would like to set a trace flag for the Process but I'm not sure it's possible to do it at the Process Level.

**Is it possible to set a trace flag on a Single Process, or do I have to set it on a per user basis?**

Additional Information: 
The issue is not that the Process Builder is failing. It is that the Node's criteria is met, but it's not doing it's assigned actions. Below is the logic for the Nodes. **I think it might have something to do with the fact that we are doing an update in Node 1, and this Update to the record that started the process is supposed to fire Node 2**

This is the logic further down the Process builder at

```
Node 1, 
  IF(Opp stage = x AND checkbox = true, update: Opp Stage = y ) 

Node 2 says if Opp Stage = y then update checkbox2 = true AND Run Invocable method –
```

Comment: per user is what you've got to work with.

Comment: I have found that you can search the debug logs. Through the APEXLog, but that doesn't really help if your operation is /aura

Comment: Don't you get an email with the details of the failed Process Builder?  Usually this is enough to figure out the issue

Comment: That's the problem is that it's not failing. It's meeting the criteria of a node that updates the record. The update occurs, but then the next node does not fire consistently.

Comment: Problem is the 7th node never runs.

Comment: please use [edit] to provide the additional details, not comments

Comment: Added removed comments to post. Thanks @cropredy.